# Basic non-inverting op-amp circuit is not working

Tags: operational-amplifier

Here is a basic non-inverting op-amp circuit, but it's doing my head-in.

I assembled five of these and the output is wrong at 4.2 V with an input of 3.3 V; the output should be around 11.5 V. The results are the same for all five boards.

The mounted resistors all have the correct values (after de-soldering). The U1 footprint is correct. The supply is at 12 V.

[image]

Resistance reading when soldered back to board:

R3 = 3 kΩ
R1 = 4.92 kΩ

U1 pin 6 to ground = 5.5 kΩ

What's happening here?

[image]

Comment: Capacitors at the output are pretty much the worst thing you could do to an opamp. Remove C3. It makes the opamp unstable.

Answer (score 1):

problem solved!

OUTPUT pin is clamped with a 3.3V TVS device. Duh.

Comment: Well, you get to select your own answer given a wait period, I guess. :)

Comment: C3 is also very probably a problem. What's it doing there?

Answer (score 1):

The output capacitor is the culprit. The opamp don't have that much capacitive load drive capability. This capacitor reduces the PM of the system. Please see the simulation result below. Could you please remove the output capacitor and recheck.

[image]